# Calling a AWS Lambda function from Jenkins post build action

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

My requirement is to call an AWS lambda function from the post build action , I know HTTP-Request" plugin and lambda Api gateway can work , but is there any other better approach?

Comment: I haven't used this but did you look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWS+Lambda+Plugin?

Comment: Didn't do it myself, but you can invoke shell and from shell you can do aws cli call.

Comment: You can also use AWS CLI command to execute Lambda after post build action.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe AWS [**Chalice**](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/build-and-deploy-a-serverless-rest-api-in-minutes-using-chalice/) could help. For instance:

```
$ chalice new-project helloworld
$ cd helloworld
```

Then

```
$ chalice deploy
```

As it is deployed by script you could use Jenkins.